# Accessbiliy issue with Calendar ctrl pageup while JAWS is running

Tags: calendar, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I'm trying to change year of datepicker using Ctrl + PageUp of below URL

http://oaa-accessibility.org/example/15/

It is working fine till I launch [JAWS](http://www.freedomscientific.com/Products/Blindness/JAWS), Once I launched JAWS its not working.

We observed it is changing month instead of year. For month change shortcut is pageUp. In code we are getting ctrlKey as false and assuming user pressed only PageUp and responding to that request.

It might be overlapping with shortcut keys with JAWS

Can some one help me understand how to make Ctrl + PageUp working while JAWS is running. 
is it mandatory to have Ctrl+Pageup to change year of calendar to meet accessibility guidelines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the response which I got from JAWS tech support team

When position on the item where I wanted to perform the control+page up command on, I had to perform the insert+Number row 3 command to allow the next keystroke to pass through and then perform the keystroke and it worked properly for me.